# how can I change a char in string

Tags: c

I know that you can not change a char in string if the string is a pointer, but I initialize the string as an array, but I still can not change the string right now:

```
char temp[50];
FILE * f = fopen ( "123.txt", "r" );
while ( fscanf( f, "%s", temp ) != EOF )
{
  temp[2] = " ";
}
fclose(f);
```

It still shows

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]
```

what should I do with it?

Comment: do `temp[2] = ' '` you cannot assign a string to a char

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443316/why-does-the-compiler-issue-warning-assignment-makes-integer-from-pointer-with (I accidentally cast my close vote for something else)

Comment: `you cannot assign a string to a char` actually he can but probably the effect of this assignment will not be exactly the same as his intentions :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you it works now, I just started to learn c, and my assignment asked me to count the occurrence of the words in a txt file, but there are a lot of symbols and space which I have to delete it; I am trying to change all the symbols to space then use strtok to get those words.

Comment: `temp[2] = ' ';` or `temp[2] = 32;`

Comment: A pointer is a pointer, neither a string nor an array. C does not even have a string type.

Comment: @i486 Sadly it's not possible to downvote comments. But why do you suggest `temp[2] = 32;`? that's terrible style.

Comment: @HaotianSong, please note that you can scan the file character by character and create a state machine, a very simple one. Ignore all the characters that you want to, every time you find a word delimiter you increase the count, and change the state to `IN_WORD`, when you are in state `IN_WORD` you simply reset the state to `SEARCHING`, and so on.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi With `' '` somebody may not see the space - for that reason I added `= 32` alternative. BTW, in my opinion this is not terrible style - quite the contrary (at least if you remember the ASCII table). Terrible style is to write `temp[2] = '\0'` instead of `temp[2] = 0`.

Comment: @i486 I again can't downvote your comment. Because `'\0'` is a good way to make clear that you are addressing the *null* terminator. I can't believe that you think using ascii values directly is better than character constants, for code readability it's clearly better to use character constants, but since this is a opinion I respect yours, so please do not answer my comment.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I agree with you - I also cannot downvote your comments! About ASCII values, it is exception for space code (32) and some other specific codes like double quotes, etc. For regular letter or sign of course is normal to put it quoted and readable. PS: Assigning  `'\0'` is one of the most stupid things that I have seen. Unfortunately, many people do it.

Comment: @i486 that really is a horrible style. If you have a `char` type, use `char` literals, not integer literals. I don't even think that ASCII is guaranteed, so using an integer constant `32` would not be portable.

Comment: @PCLuddite O, yes. We have to be prepared for EBCDIC.

Comment: @i486 You forgot to say *Unfortunately **many smart people** do it*.

Comment: @i486 you're setting yourself up for failure with that mentality. You've got one way that works 99.99% of the time, and one way that works 100% of the time. Even if they are nearly the same, why take the chance just to prove a point?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi ... mainly beginners and students. Maybe they are smart but unexperienced in C.

Comment: @i486 ASCII coding is common in C implementations but not *required*.`32` in EBCDIC character set is not **space**, it is `DS` **digit select** (although it might be non-printing). Similarly `48` is not **0**. Although few use EBCDIC there is no reason an implementation cannot invent its own table. The only requirement is that the digits **0** to **9** representations are consecutive.

Comment: @i486 I would expect to see `temp[2] = 32` in beginners code.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe you have not understood my comment for EBCDIC. I know there 32 is not space. But what is the chance to write software now and need portability for EBCDIC? If there is such project, you can be sure that the programmer will be very experienced and will know main part of ASCII and EBCDIC codes by heart.

Comment: @i486 of course not, that was example not reality. Just do things properly from the start, and not use a poor excuse that someone might misread `' '` for `''`. C has to be ***exact*** and a fine reading skill goes with it. I miss things, but still choose to code in C.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you use C for long time (e.g. 20 years) then `' '`, `32`, and `0x20` become obviously the same thing (value). And `c = 32` (`c = 0x20`) is readable at least like `c = ' '` or better in many cases.

Comment: @i486 no. `' '` and `32` are "obviously the same thing" only to a beginner. They can be different. If you want **space** use `' '`. If you want a **0** use `'0'`. End of.

Comment: regarding: `while ( fscanf( f, "%s", temp ) != EOF )`  1)  when using the input format specifier '%s' (or '%[...]')  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any possibility of overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  1 less because those two input format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input. (cont)

Comment: (cont) 2)  When working with the `scanf()` family of functions, it is best to check for a positive result.  I.E. `while ( fscanf( f, "%s", temp ) != ` ) { fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for a string from a file failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }   // implied else, fscanf successful`

Answer (score 1):

this statement:

```
temp[2] = " ";
```

is trying to assign a string to an individual character

Suggest using:

```
temp[2] = ' ';
```

which is assigning a character to a character.

Note the single quotes rather than double quotes